# Keeping Ajax alive to prevent firewall timeout

Tags: ajax

I've an Ajax request which fires up a PHP script. It can take a couple of minutes for the data to be calculated and returned. This is fine within the company network but from outside it gets cut off after 30 seconds by the company firewall. We can't change the firewall timeout. Is there a way I can keep this Ajax connection alive??
Thanks

Comment: Maybe chunk your request, that is you send the request to the server to start doing the calculation. Then long poll every 10 seconds, for example, to check if the computation is complete, then return results.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I need. I have the function to calculate the data working fine. I've read how to do long polling, so will work that into my JavaScript now... Do you have any example of how I actually check that the initial function is complete? Is it a case of writing a response to file and then checking for presence of file and requesting its contents??? That doesn't should like the efficient solution! I expect I'm missing some simple method?? Thanks